# No puedo guardar los datos de ckeditor en mysql

Tags: ckeditor

He leido varias consultas y ninguna me ha servido de como guardar los datos recompilados en ckeditor, para ir al grano les explico:

basado en los ejemplos, he amarrado en "textarea" el ckeditor e hice este valor para que ingrese a la base de datos:

```
<?php $descripcion= mysqli_real_escape_string($con,($_POST['descripcion'])); ?>
```

en el html:

```
<textarea class="form-control" style="height:450px;width:560px;" id="descripcion" required name="descripcion" value="descripcion"></textarea>
```

javascript:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script> CKEDITOR.replace( 'descripcion' ); </script>
```

Revise el código que genera ckeditor y vi que el campo de trabajo esta fuera del textarea, ahora de aqui viene la famosa pregunta:

¿habrá una orden en Jquery del ckeditor para que pueda escribir correctamente en el textarea? ó
¿Habrá una forma de usar el campo de ckeditor para que pueda usarlo para cambiar los valores y que pueda registrarlo en el mysqli?

Espero que no los moleste por esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando `Jquery` para mandar lo que escribes en el textarea a la base de datos, debes saber que `ckEditor` solo funciona con `JavaScript` puro, pero por suerte los mismos creadores lo han adaptado para poder utlizar `JQuery` (Tendras que buscar la cdn del adaptador). Si descargas `Ckeditor`, y abres la carpeta, veras que hay una carpeta llamada `adapters`, dentro de esa carpeta esta el archivo `.js` que debes incluir en tu proyecto para poder utilizar `JQuery` y mandarlo a la base de datos

La documentacion de el adaptador sugiere que debes incluirlo despues de

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Te dejo el link de la documentacion del adaptador
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_jquery.html

Answer (score -1):

[Puedes ver en esta dirección la forma de guardar los datos del CKEDITOR](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_savedata)